# Tracing a possibly invented quotation (Adorno?)

Tags: artificial-intelligence, critical-theory, quote

SE has quite rightly banned, for now, "answers" generated by ChatGPT -- but this is a question derived from there.  Here is the session we had, with me setting it up with an Arendt quotation:

```
Q: What is the source of the following quotation? 
"Before the alternative of facing the anarchic growth and total arbitrariness
of decay or bowing down before the most rigid, fantastically fictitious 
consistency of an ideology, the masses probably will always choose the latter 
and be ready to pay for it with individual sacrifices -- and this not because 
they are stupid or wicked, but because in the general disaster this escape 
grants them a minimum of self-respect." 

A: Theodor Adorno, Minima Moralia: Reflections from Damaged Life, 1951 
[Wrong -- it's Arendt: OoT, pg 352 in my edition]

Q: Can you cite the chapter in which that quotation occurs? 

A: Chapter 44, "The Power of the False". 

Q: What is the first paragraph of that chapter? 

A: "It is usually assumed that the masses are more readily deceived by ideology 
than individuals. This is only an apparent truth; rather, the masses accept the 
false totality of the prevailing system more quickly and more thoroughly than 
do individuals, because they are not in a position to measure the whole against 
their own experience." 

Q: What is the source of that paragraph? 

A: Theodor Adorno, Minima Moralia: Reflections from Damaged Life, 1951, Chapter 44, 
"The Power of the False".
```

Now *Minima Moralia*, Aphorism 44 is actually "For post-Socratics" and does not include the alleged paragraph, nor is it on this topic.  My English *Minima Moralia* is in a box somewhere but I don't think there's any aphorism called "The Power of the False", though that's certainly a very Adorno title.  The alleged second quotation is also pretty Adorno -- and yet I haven't been able to dig it up through any web search.  Can anyone identify this imaginary assertion for me?  Or has OpenAI developed Artificial Frankfurt School?

I should note that this was the second time I'd asked it to source my Arendt quotation; the first time it said it was from Horkheimer's *Traditional and Critical Theory*.  And prior to those queries I had asked it who the *author* of the quotation was and it correctly said Arendt.  So anyway it's got some sense of schools.

Comment: To clarify, you're asking about the *second* paragraph ("It is usually assumed ..."), right? The first paragraph is from Arendt, *The origins of totalitarianism*, section 3.11.1.

Comment: Correct, @NoahSchweber; sorry, I'll see if I can make that clearer.  Anyway, that [ ] square-bracketed line is where I put the right attribution on the first quotation.